# MYSQL left join if then statement favorite table procedure

Tags: php, mysql, variables, if-statement, user-defined

i have 2 tables
here is table 1 table name is 
forexample

itemlist

```
+-----+----------+-----+  
| uid | username | age |  
+-----+----------+-----+  
|   1 | doe      |  17 |  
|   2 | smith    |  18 |  
|   3 | john     |  30 |  
+-----+----------+-----+
```

and other one is

fav

```
+-----+------+---------+
| uid | user | itemuid |
+-----+------+---------+
|   1 | alex |       2 |
+-----+------+---------+
```

Here is my mysql query *NOT Working * any way to fix this problem when i run php file i got error in mysql syntax

```
SELECT c.uid, c.username, c.age,i.uid,i.user,i.itemuid 
from itemlist c 
left join fav i on c.uid = i.itemuid 
if (i.user = 'alex') THEN 
SET @fav = 1;
ELSE
SET @fav = 0;
END IF
```

this is sample php

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    if ($row['fav'] = '1'){
            echo $row['username']." is exit in fav";
        }else{
            echo $row['username']." is not exit in fav";
    }
}
```

i hope you understand my question right ?

Comment: You want us to do your code for you? Is this the question?

Comment: Sorry Bro .... i just edit this question

Comment: You can't use `IF...THEN...END IF` in a normal SQL query.

Comment: SO how it's done ? any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a column named `fav` returned in the resultset, you would need to include an expression in the SELECT list, and give it an alias `fav`.

It's not at all clear why you would need a MySQL user-defined variable; if you don't know why you'd need one, then you probably don't need one.

Given that your PHP code is looking for a column named `fav` in the resultset, likely you want something like this:

```
SELECT c.uid
     , c.username
     , c.age
     , i.uid AS i_uid
     , i.user
     , i.itemuid
     , IF(i.user='alex',1,0) AS fav
  FROM itemlist c 
  LEFT
  JOIN fav i ON i.itemuid  = c.uid
```

Note that the original query had two columns named `uid`; if you want to return both, and be able to reference both of those by column name, you need to have distinct names for each. In the query above, I've assigned an alias to the `i.uid` column so that both `uid` columns will be available by distinct  column name.

Comment: thank you sir you saved my time you are the best love you .... i don't know why people down my vote...

Comment: Sometimes, getting a simple example of how something is typically done is all that is needed. To me, it looks like you had done some research, and you tried something, and you were ready for help. Good luck!